# How to increment the string value?

Tags: java, string

For example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
String a="1";
int inc= Integer.parseInt(a+1);
System.out.println(inc);

 }
```

I'm getting 11 but i want to get 2. How can i do it in a very efficient way?

Comment: Integer.parseInt(a)+1;

Comment: Thanks this worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt(a+1);` parses the `String` that results from concatenating the value of the `String` `a` ("1") to the `int` literal `1`, which is "11".

Change it to

```
int inc = Integer.parseInt(a) + 1;
```

This way "a" would be parsed to the integer `1` and then `1` would be added to it to give you the value `2`.

Comment: @Nolimits Sorry, that was a typo - fixed to `Integer.parseInt(a) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Since **a** is a String object this operation is not giving the desired input

```
Integer.parseInt(a+1);
```

because will be equivalent to do

```
Integer.parseInt("1"+"1");
```

or

```
Integer.parseInt("11");
```

you need to parse the string first and then increment

```
 Integer.parseInt(a)+1
```